# Regex that does not match number if surrounded by specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a regex which will match some content (which contains repeats) but only if it's not preceded by an equals character (=) and only if it's not followed by an ampersand character (&).

So for example let's say the content to match is represented by `CONTENT`.  I don't think it matters much what it is for this issue, only that the content that's being matched is quite long, such that I cannot duplicate all of it in the application I'm using.  `CONTENT` can appear anywhere in a blob, and it might be the only thing too.

```
CONTENT         // OK, should match
fooCONTENT      // OK, should match
CONTENTfoo      // OK, should match
fooCONTENTfoo   // OK, should match
=CONTENT        // OK, should match
CONTENT&        // OK, should match
=CONTENT&       // NO - SHOULD NOT MATCH
```

I tried something like this for the pattern:

```
(?!=CONTENT&)CONTENT...
```

But it does not work to exclude `=CONTENT&` , probably because the regex engine simply moves past the leading `=` and then the lookahead is met.

I considered doing a negative lookbehind following `CONTENT`, but since CONTENT contains repeats it's not possible (look behinds must have a fixed length pattern).

Comment: Are you trying to match an individual string, or could this content appear anywhere in a text, for example?

Comment: `^[^=].*[^&]$` would match the pattern you want.

Comment: What does it mean when you say *CONTENT repeats itself* ?

Comment: `CONTENT` contains repeats meaning things followed by +, *, and/or {N}.

Comment: `[^=].*[^&]` is interesting (and simple to boot).  Seems I've been over thinking it.  Only issue with that solution (I think) is that it requires at least one char before and after it.  So if `CONTENT` were at the beginning or end of the blob (or if it's the entirety of the blob), then it won't match.
In my case, that requirement is probably not a problem.
Another issue is that the character before and the character after will be part of the _matched_ content, whereas I'd like only `CONTENT`

Comment: On further looking, `[^=].*[^&]` does not work.  The following cases are not matched: `=CONTENT` and `CONTENT&`

Comment: @codesniffer: If you let us know the programming language/tool you are using, it  would be easier to help. I think you need to use an old technique: match and capture what you need and just match what you do not need. Use [`=[^=&]+&|([^=&]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ukloQ2/1) and only grab what is in Group 1.

Comment: If your CONTENT cannot contain whitespaces, `=[^\s=&]+&|([^\s=&]+)` is better.

Comment: Should any part of foo=CONTENT&bar get matched? or only exclude with the line starts with = and end with $? Assuming it has to start and end with =&, this regex should do     ^(=.*[^&]|[^=].*)$ Otherwise, CONTENT needs to be a fixed length for negative lookback.

Comment: Forget about lookarounds, you do not need them. Once it is clear what is necessary here, the answer will be very simple, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to match `Content` **either** preceded by an `=` OR succeeded by `&` but **not both at same time.**

You can achieve it by using **alteration** as follows.

**Regex:** `^=?[^=&]+$|^[^=&]+&?$`

**Explanation:**

`^=?[^=&]+$` looks for an optional `=` followed by more than one characters other than `=` and `&`.

`^[^=&]+&?$` looks for more than one characters other than `=` and `&` followed by an optional `&`.

`|` is alteration which forces to match with either of declared patterns.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B8znlt/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.  It's an interesting approach.  I'll give it a shot, but in my case I have lookarounds before and after the "main" part of the match.  And the main part of the match contains lookarounds inside, so it cannot be put into a character set.  Can alteration like this be used with patterns that cannot be put into a character set?

Comment: @codesniffer: Could you explain that in your question ? I am not following you.

Comment: Imagine the pattern for my number is something like this:  `(?!123|222|999)\d{3}(?:[ ]+|[-_]?[ ]+)\d{5,7}(?![\d-])` (the actual is more complex than that).  Can such a pattern be used with your suggestion, considering it can't be placed inside a character set?

Comment: If you mean can it replace `[ ]+|[-_]?[ ]+` then yes. Because it's inside a non-capturing group and it won't affect the lookaround assertions. But then anchors `^` and `$` has to go depending upon your _complex_ regex.

Comment: @codesniffer: I think you should lay down your original specifications and attempts you have made. That way you might get better response from community.

Comment: Couple things.  I need to detect the pattern only when it's not surrounded with both `=` and `&`.  That means either one can be there OR neither can be there, and it should match.  The other thing is that the pattern is fairly large and my application provides limited space.  So I probably cannot duplicate it for alteration.